# Issues with wxwidgets and VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, wxwidgets, vcpkg

OS: linux

IDE: VSCode

complier: CMake but I can use another if better results are given

Hello I am wanting to learn how to apply c++ for cross platform development. I have chose to use WxWidgets, however, after compiling I ran into an issue, I could not integrate WxWidgets. I tried using vcpkg because it seemed simpler to integrate I ran the following after the ./vcpkg integrate install

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/places/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

I then got the issue

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

I pretty certain I am not missing the libraries and that the issue lies in configuration.
Here is part of my CMakeLists.txt

```
 set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswu)`
 SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "home/places/wxwidget/wxWidgets-3.1.4/")
 SET(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES "home/places/wxwidget/wxWidgets-3.1.4/lib/")
 SET(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "home/places/wxWidgets-3.1.4/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1.so")
 SET(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION "mswd")
 find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED)
 include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
```

I also tried the wxwidgets-vscode helloworld found here https://github.com/huckor/wxwidgets-vscode/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json

I really appreciate any help and thankyou.

Comment: Toolchain `vcpkg.cmake` helps to `find_package` to locate packages installed by vcpkg. So, have you installed wxWidgets using vcpkg? How exactly have you installed wxWidgets?

Comment: @theencomputers, what version of wxWidgets are you trying to use?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok this is probably me just being clueless i managed to get passed the Libraries not found and run the cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/places/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake I then added `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(Test ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})` to the cmakelists file but when I type #include <wx>  it still cannot find wxwidgets. I appreciate the help

Comment: Even though I managed to run the command i still get `  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)`

Comment: Thank you I put the command in my tasks.json and configured my includePath to satisfy VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following

1. Open the Terminal.
2. Do `cd </path/to/your/source/code>.
3. Do

   g++ -o <your_binary_name> `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` *.cpp

Did it work?

Thank you.

BTW, `CMake` is not a compiler - its a tool to generate Makefile and project files for different IDEs.